# Node js using alert().authenticateAs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

Using the node.js version of selenium I need to enter in auth information into an alert.  I haven't been successful at using the 'authenticateAs' function, does anyone have any example of this function in use.

I can not simply add the user:password to the beginning of the url because the url is coming from a redirect

I'd really like to use this: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_AlertPromise.html#authenticateAs

Comment: What is the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Basic http auth doesn't seem to be directly supported by WebDriver. According to [the conversation here](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/385), it's being pushed to v2 of the spec (v1 is still in the process of being implemented).